# Multiple CountDistinct with IIF Statements

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have a formula that is counting the number of records based on certain criteria: Group number of 1, 2, 3 etc.
I would like to include all of the possible criteria, and count each accordingly in the same field. It will populate based on the section.

I have this formula in the Expression.

```
=COUNTDISTINCT(IIF(Fields!GroupNum.Value = 1 AND Fields!TenName.Value <> "" AND NOT(Fields!Unit.Value LIKE "*WAIT*"),Fields!Unit.Value,Nothing))
OR
COUNTDISTINCT(IIF(Fields!GroupNum.Value = 2 AND Fields!TenName.Value <> "", Fields!Unit.Value,Nothing))
```

This receives an error.

I have also tried it like this:

```
=COUNTDISTINCT(IIF(Fields!GroupNum.Value = 1 AND Fields!TenName.Value <> "" AND NOT(Fields!Unit.Value LIKE "*WAIT*"),Fields!Unit.Value,Nothing))
=COUNTDISTINCT(IIF(Fields!GroupNum.Value = 2 AND Fields!TenName.Value <> "", Fields!Unit.Value,Nothing))
```

This will display True or False.

Comment: Explain the logic you are trying to apply, with examples, at the moment we can see the problem code but it's hard to suggest a solution unless we know what you want to do. What I would say is that you can't have count distinct used with an OR like that.

Comment: I am trying to count the number of units affected and put this result in the same field. For example: if it is group number '1' it would count the number of units in that group. If not, it would count the next group '2'' and so on. The report has multiple sections based on the Groups. This is done in the SQL

Comment: Can you edit your question and post a sample of data as text or a script to generate it (as it is returned from your dataset query) and what you expect the output to look like based on the sample data.